# Creating menu bar in css/html responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I want to ask you how to make my menu bar responsive to all devices. I have used that one video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOWjWRy_Kks&t=258s . When I open it from my laptop everything looks cool but when i try to open it from my other devices ( tablet or my smartphone ) I can't see my menu.

```js
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
        $('nav').addClass('black');
      } else {
        $('nav').removeClass('black');
      }
    })
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Quicksand;
}


/*Menu Bar*/

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: .3s;
}

nav.black {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px 100px;
}

nav .logo {
  padding: 22px 20px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: .3s;
}

nav.black .logo {
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  line-height: 80px;
  color: #151515;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: .3s;
}

nav.black ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a: focus {
  outline: none;
}

nav ul li a.active {
  background: #E2472F;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

section.sec1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(img/backgroud.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 80px;
}


}

/*Media*/
@media(max-width: 580px) {
  nav ul {
    max-height: 0px;
  }
  
  .logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 16px;
  }
  
  nav ul li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 24px 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
  <title> Landschaft </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:500" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--JavaScript-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
</head>
<!--Body-->

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">Landschaft</div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">НАЧАЛО</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">СЪБИТИЯ</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">ПЪТЕКИ</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">ФОРУМ</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">ВРЪЗКИ</li>   
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">ВХОД</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>


    <!--Section-->
    <section class="sec1"></section>
    <section class="content"> </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example if you want us to help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To get started quickly, look at the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please.

Comment: Here you go mates! The first code is CSS and the second is HTML.. I really hope you will help me.

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO .

Comment: @НиколаИванов ok much better. Now, what are you expecting to look like on a phone. You need to have more details in you question. Maybe even adding an image explaining the end result. A mockup would be just fine

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO I am really sorry for the poor way I am trying to explain. I am kinda new to develop websites. I want to make my website responsive to all devices. I mean when i open my website from my phone I want to see the menu bar like the way you can see it when you run code snippet on full view. I hope u understand me.. I am sorry for my bad English..

Comment: @НиколаИванов i do understand that part, but as you can see, there will not be enough space in your mobil for that big menu

Comment: @НиколаИванов let me try something

Comment: I really don't know what happned but the first time when I wrote the code everything was fine, after that I wrote code for slideshow and something went wrong... I delete everything and re-wrote the whole code for NavBar and still doesn't work..

Comment: Still doesn't work... :( :(

Comment: That will do. Thank you really much! I appreciate the help mate!

Answer (score 0):

This what i can do for this kind of code. I can still help you if you comment on what you want to improve

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
        $('nav').addClass('black');
      } else {
        $('nav').removeClass('black');
      }
    })
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Quicksand;
}


/*Menu Bar*/

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: .3s;
}

nav.black {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px 100px;
}

nav .logo {
  padding: 22px 20px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: .3s;
}

nav.black .logo {
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  line-height: 80px;
  color: #151515;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: .3s;
}

nav.black ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a: focus {
  outline: none;
}

nav ul li a.active {
  background: #E2472F;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

section.sec1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(img/backgroud.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 80px;
}


}

/*Media*/
@media(max-width: 580px) {
  nav ul {
    max-height: 0px;
  }
  
  .logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 16px;
  }
  
  nav ul li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 24px 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 767px) {
  nav {padding: 5px}
  nav .logo {padding: 0}
  nav ul li a {padding: 5px}
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
  <title> Landschaft </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:500" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--JavaScript-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
</head>
<!--Body-->

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">Landschaft</div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">НАЧАЛО</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">СЪБИТИЯ</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">ПЪТЕКИ</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">ФОРУМ</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">ВРЪЗКИ</li>   
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">ВХОД</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>


    <!--Section-->
    <section class="sec1"></section>
    <section class="content"> </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Никола Иванов Did my answer help you, or did you ran into trouble?

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it like this? Look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/1tnke5w3/) fiddle if you want to try different sizes.

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
    $('nav').addClass('black');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('black');
  }
});

function toggleMenu(x) {
  x.classList.toggle('openMenu');
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: Quicksand;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*Menu Bar*/

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 0 100px;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

nav.black {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

nav .logo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 5px;
  line-height: 80px;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  text-align: center;
}

nav.black .logo {
  color: #fff;
}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12.5%;
  line-height: 80px;
  color: #151515;
  padding: 0 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: .3s;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

nav.black a {
  color: #fefefe;
}

nav a:focus {
  outline: none;
}

nav a.active {
  background: #E2472F;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

section.sec1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Widescreen-Image.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 80px;
}


/* Hamburger icon */

.hamburger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger .bar1,
.hamburger .bar2,
.hamburger .bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.openMenu .hamburger .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.openMenu .hamburger .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.openMenu .hamburger .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}


/*Media*/

@media(max-width: 860px) {
  nav {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #fefefe;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  nav a {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: calc((100vh - 80px) / 6);
    transform: translateY(80px);
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .openMenu a {
    color: #fefefe;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .hamburger {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
  }
  .openMenu {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:500" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <div class="hamburger" onclick="toggleMenu(this.parentNode);">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">Landschaft</div><a href="index.html">НАЧАЛО</a
      ><a href="about.html">СЪБИТИЯ</a
      ><a href="index.html">ПЪТЕКИ</a
      ><a href="index.html">ФОРУМ</a
      ><a href="index.html">ВРЪЗКИ</a
      ><a class="active" href="index.html">ВХОД</a>
  </nav>


  <!--Section-->
  <section class="sec1"></section>
  <section class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
    eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat
    nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt
    ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie
    consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue
    nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
    exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis. At vero eos et accusam et justo
    duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed
    diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore
    dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
    elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat. Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
    duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed
    diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
    ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
    tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
    sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
    no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit
    praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et
    accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem
    ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo
  </section>
</div>
```